# order of characters of the string in perl

Tags: string, perl

I want to write a code that regards strings with characters in different order as equal as long as same characters are placed in the strings.  For example, suppose $a = "ksv", whenever somebody input string value "svk" or "kvs", I want to write a code that these strings are equivalent to $a.  Here is an example,

```
@ans=("ksv", "kvs", "svk", "vsk",......);

if (@input[1] ~~ @ans) {
            return 'EXACT_ANS';
}
```

@input[1] is what user will put the string.  At first, I listed all of the different types of order as an array (just like the example) so that if one of elements in the array matches with @input[1], then I return it as a correct answer.  However, this is quite a long and tedious work if I have a string with much longer length.  Please give me any advice on this.  Thank you^^

Comment: Do the lengths of the two strings have to be equal? In other words, should `svksvk` also match?

Comment: As Perl will warn you, `@input[1]` is a non-standard way of writing `$input[1]`.

Comment: First of all, please don't use smart match. `$input[1] ~~ @ans` is an experimental feature that may be changed or removed from later versions of the language. The best alternative is `List::Util::first`

Comment: Secondly, if you can describe more clearly what you want to achieve then we will be able to help you better. If the strings are always three characters long then it is best just to list all of the alternatives and check each one. But if each string may be thousands of characters then Perl is the wrong choice, and you must look for a custom solution

Comment: For strings up to about 10 or 12 characters long, Perl is still useful. But you must clarify what you need to do. Will you be comparing two strings of the same length, or looking for a smaller string within a larger one? Are you dealing just with the 26 English letters, or may there be other symbols?

Comment: Thank you for all of the comments.  I have various string length from 3 to 5 and the user will input strings which can be any length.  So I have to check two things 1. the input string length has to match with the strings I have.  2. the order doesn't matter but the character in the string should match.  I will try the one in the answer below and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You want something of the form

```
if (normalize_string($input) eq normalize_string('ksv')) {
   ...
}
```

where `normalize_string` is a sub that returns the same string for all equivalent inputs, and returns different strings for inputs that aren't equivalent.

---

The exact definition of `normalize_string` will vary based on what you consider equivalent.

If you want to ignore duplicate characters (`abbc` is equivalent to `abc`):

```
sub normalize_string {
   my %h;
   ++$h{$_} for split //, $_[0];
   return join '', sort keys %h;
}
```

If the number of instances of each character is pertinent (`abbc` isn't equivalent to `abc`):

```
sub normalize_string {
   return join '', sort split //, $_[0];
}
```

---

Of course, you can inline the normalized form when the parameter is a constant.

```
if (normalize_string($input) eq 'ksv') {
   ...
}
```